# reduce voltage for inverter in solar system

Tags: voltage, inverter, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I have a solar system (solar panel, controller, battery and inverter).
Battery have standby use 13.6-13.8V, cycle use 14.5-15V. I set the charging voltage to 13.8V.

The problem is that inverter to 230 AC is designed to 12V and it disconnect on voltage about 13.4V.
(So it disconnect when solar is connected and charging).

How I should reduce the voltage for the inverter? (and keep it optimal for the battery)

Comment: It sounds like you need to replace your inverter with one which is compatible with your system voltage.

Answer (score 1):

Seems unusual that inverter cuts out at 13.4V, considering a battery in vehicle can get to 14.4V when charging. Any inverter designed for 12V input would expect to be running off vehicle 12V system. I would suggest you don't try to reduce voltage, as you'll lose precious power. Better to double check your inverter is configured for 12V battery input or get one that works above 13.4V. If you're only option is to reduce the voltage, use an efficient step down DC-DC to give constant 12V.